# Return object bound to a dynamic element when label for object is also dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor.  Within my page, the user can dynamically add/remove the element containing the WYSIWYG ckeditor text editor.

`CKEDITOR.instances` returns an object which contains within it all the ck_editor objects on my page.

When the user clicks the `add` button, then the following code successfully grabs that element:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[“my_textarea_0_body"]
```

The issue is when the user clicks `delete` to remove that element, and then reclicks `add`.  I now want to grab that *new* ckeditor element on the page.  However, now I need to grab it with this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[“my_textarea_1_body"]
```

Notice that the number changed.  So, the user is able to toggle the add/remove of this element any number of times.  Example: if they did it 100 times I would need to have a way to grab that object like so:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[“my_textarea_100_body"]
```

The problem is that I never know what that number will be.  That number is vital for me to create the string in order to grab the appropriate object.

**Question**: How can I grab this dynamically labeled object that is contained within the `CKEDITOR.instances` object?  I know that my desired object will always be the LAST object appended within that `CKEDITOR.instances` object.

Comment: Im about 95% sure you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - ie, you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @Jamiec I totally agree that that is probably the issue.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Describe the problem you're trying to solve - not how you think you should be solving it. Directly from the upvoted answer in my link `To avoid falling into this trap, always include information about a broader picture along with any attempted solution.`

Comment: @Jamiec how can I provide an attempted solution when I do not know how to go about solving it?  Especially if the issue is that the way I am thinking about the issue is incorrect?  I was hoping people could help me with that part if that is the issue. I would gladly make this question more broad if I was able to identify exactly where my problem lies.

Comment: Read that again! You've provided the "attempted solution" It is probably wrong. You need to provide the "broader picture". To be more specific you've said `I have the following which returns an object:` ... where do you get that from? What provides it? Why do you generate dynamic fields with a number in them? With some of this info we might be able to get you a better solution to the problem.

Comment: @Jamiec it is not always easy to write a question perfectly the first go.  Sometimes it takes some dialogue between the person asking the question and the responders.  With their help, I was able to update my question so that it is better suited for the long term.

Comment: I thought thats what I was helping you to do. Anyway glad you got a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `CKEDITOR.instancess` a kind of a map (dictionary), so you can get all key names by [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). And then select the last/first/ or n-th instance name.

```
var mapping_length = Object.keys(CKEDITOR.instances).length;
var object_label   = Object.keys(CKEDITOR.instances)[mapping_length - 1];
CKEDITOR.instances[object_label];
```

This will return the desired object from within that dictionary object.

Comment: trouble is that I do not know what the index would be.  Since it is dynamic: the user might delete and then add 1 time, 20 times, 100 times.  I want to match for all those cases.

Comment: You have been extremely helpful!  You are right: `Object.keys(CKEDITOR.instances)` does the trick.  With that, I can just grab the last one, which is the one that I want. (I realized that as the objects were deleted/re-added to the page it was just appending a new object in that list.  I want to give you credit.  If you wouldn't mind updating your answer, then I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Regex indeed is your friend here. `/^CKEDITOR\.instances\["my_textarea_\d+_body"\]$/.test(str)` should get the job done. (if you copy and paste any of your initial examples to test, it will fail however since you've got an angled quote illegal character in there)

```js
console.log(/^CKEDITOR\.instances\["my_textarea_\d+_body"\]$/.test('CKEDITOR.instances["my_textarea_0_body"]'))
```

I think I understand what you're getting at though - you know the vague structure of the key, but not exactly what it will be when you're trying to retrieve it. In that case, you'd want to search through the keys of the `CKEDITOR.instances` object for any that match that pattern. So, `let matchingKeys = Object.keys(CKEDITOR.instances).filter(key => /^my_textarea_\d+_body$/.test(key))`. That will return a set of all keys that match that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function which checks for a regex match. The regex for that field should be:

```
my_textarea_\d+_body
```

Then you can modify/add the new object key to instances